# Из-за прав не могу сохранять файл в brackets и atom, почему?

Tags: atom, brackets

Из-за прав не могу сохранять файл в  brackets и atom, почему?!
Вот, что выходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ОС винда!

Answer (score 1):

Не можете сохранить файл из-за того что изменяете его в директории, в которой не имеете прав на запись. Создайте/скопируйте проект в другую директорию, измените права на папку и вложенные объекты, или используйте учетную запись, которая обладает такими правами (администратор).

Для записи в C:/Program files - нужны права администратора

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаете проект в стартовом проекте. Попробуйте создать новый проект, там проблем возникнуть не должно...